# Issue with declaring Tesseract OCR TessBaseAPI

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tesseract

I am new to Tesseract API. Currently I am running the sample program from the Wiki on Visual Studio 2013, and the program is as follows.

```
#include "leptonica\allheaders.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "api\baseapi.h"
#include "stdio.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace tesseract;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
char* outText;

TessBaseAPI *api = new TessBaseAPI();

// Initialize tesseract-ocr with English, without specifying tessdata path
if (api->Init(NULL, "eng")) 
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not initialize tesseract.\n");
    exit(1);
}

// Open input image with leptonica library
Pix *image = pixRead("/usr/src/tesseract-3.02/phototest.tif");
api->SetImage(image);
// Get OCR result
outText = api->GetUTF8Text();
printf("OCR output:\n%s", outText);

// Destroy used object and release memory
api->End();
delete[] outText;
pixDestroy(&image);

return 0;
}
```

When I compile this with VS2013, I get the following errors.

```
1>------ Build started: Project: OCRTest, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  main.cpp
1>c:\tesseract-build\include\leptonica\pix.h(209): warning C4305: 'initializing' : truncation        from 'double' to 'const l_float32'
1>c:\tesseract-build\include\leptonica\pix.h(211): warning C4305: 'initializing' : truncation from 'double' to 'const l_float32'
1>c:\tesseract-build\tesseract-ocr\api\baseapi.h(32): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'platform.h': No such file or directory
 ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I believe I have not built the tesseract source properly, but I cannot be sure. Also, declaring

```
TessBaseAPI * api = new TessBaseAPI()
```

throws up errors such as 'type specifier expected' when cursor is moved over TessBaseAPI(). Help would be greatly appreciated, and thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you try steps mentioned in my answer? My answer helped?

Comment: It turned out the tesseract Headers were all in separate directories, and to solve that issue I wrote a script to aggregate all the headers in one folder. I used that folder in my include directories slot in VS, and voila the problem was solved. Thank you very much for taking the time to answer, though.

Comment: You should never aggregate all headers in one folder. what if those headers are including headers from other directors. you would have to change every header file, why complicate the things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are using Tesseract 3.02.02 & leptonica 1.68 library.

Follow these steps.

1. Remember to check `Tesseract Development files` option when installing Tesseract
2. Add below Include folders in `Project solutions -> VC++ Directories`

   > ```
   > C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\include
   > C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\include\tesseract
   > C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\include\leptonica
   > ```
3. Add below lib folder in `Project solutions -> VC++ Directories`

   > C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\lib
4. Add additional dependencies in `Configuration Properties -> Linker->Input ->Additional Dependencies`

   > ```
   > libtesseract302.lib
   > libtesseract302d.lib
   > liblept168.lib
   > liblept168d.lib
   > ```
5. General program structure

> ```html
> > 
> >     #include <baseapi.h>
> >     #include <allheaders.h>
> >     #include <iostream>
> > 
> >     using namespace std;
> > 
> >     int main(void)
> >     {
> >      tesseract::TessBaseAPI api;
> >      //...
> >     }
> > 
> >
> ```

Comment: can you tell me how i can perform these steps in vs 2015

Comment: VS 2015 is not very different from VS 2013